# Python class opens MySQLdb in __init_. When to close it?

Tags: python, mysql, python-multithreading

I am trying to make python script that uses threading and MySQL connect. The script pulls out data from an external device and inserts it in MySQL database. I use MySQLdb as a database connector since the server on witch the script will does not have other means of connecting to mysql via python. 
The real question is this when to open and close MySQL connections in the threads. 
What I am doing right now is to open the connection in the `run` function but that way if I have static methods as for example `getValues` I should open new connection to MySQL. What I think is to open connection in the `__init__` section of the class so that I can use `self.connection` in every function. **But** here comes the problem when to close the **connection** and the **cursor** I've used till now? 
Here is and example code of what I'm **doing** right **now**:

```
class readMe(threading.Thread):

def __init__ (self,cm_config,db_config):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.exit_event=threading.Event()
    if not db_config:
        db_config={'db_host':'localhost',
                   'db_user':'root',
                   'db_pwrd':'pwrd',
                   'db_name':'test'}
    self.db_config=db_config
def run(self):
    try:
        vruzkaUstroistva = MySQLdb.connect(self.db_config['db_host'], self.db_config['db_user'], self.db_config['db_pwrd'], self.db_config['db_name']);
        vurzkaUstroistva_cur=Cursor(vruzkaUstroistva)
        vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute("SET NAMES UTF8");
        .....
        vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute(query1)
        vruzkaUstroistva.commit()
    except ConnectionException, e:
        query1 = (" INSERT INTO `Danni`")
        vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute(query1)
        vruzkaUstroistva.commit()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
        pass
    finally:
        if vruzkaUstroistva:
        vurzkaUstroistva_cur.close()
        vruzkaUstroistva.close()
```

Here is and example of what I am **trying** to do:

```
  class readMe(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self,cm_config,db_config):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.exit_event=threading.Event()
        if not db_config:
            db_config={'db_host':'localhost',
                       'db_user':'root',
                       'db_pwrd':'pwrd',
                       'db_name':'test'}
        self.db_config=db_config
        self.vruzka = MySQLdb.connect(self.db_config['db_host'], self.db_config['db_user'], self.db_config['db_pwrd'], self.db_config['db_name']);
    def run(self):
        try:
            vruzkaUstroistva = self.vruzka
            vurzkaUstroistva_cur=Cursor(vruzkaUstroistva)
            vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute("SET NAMES UTF8");
            .....
            vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute(query1)
            vruzkaUstroistva.commit()
        except ConnectionException, e:
            query1 = (" INSERT INTO `Danni`")
            vurzkaUstroistva_cur.execute(query1)
            vruzkaUstroistva.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
            pass
        finally:
            if vurzkaUstroistva_cur:
                vurzkaUstroistva_cur.close()
    def __del__:
        if vruzkaUstroistva:
            vruzkaUstroistva.close()
```

Comment: What is wrong with opening and closing the connection as needed?

Comment: Well I think that it is too often for example I have 16 devices for every device there are times that is needed to open 20 connections at a time. I am not an expert but I think that it is too much for one device to open 20 connections. Is it problem to do it that way.

Comment: As your class is a Thread, it's `run` method will (probably) be used only once, as a thread can only be started once. So there shouldn't be a difference in the number of used connections between your two cases. Some errors you have in your second class: `def __del__:` is invalid syntax, should be `def __del__(self):`, and you need to use `self.vruzka` in your `__del__` method

Comment: Ok it thread will be ran only ones but I start thread for every device every 5 seconds. For that reason I plan on using single connection for every single thread. I see that my syntax is invalid and I will fix it in my script. Thank you.

Comment: Using a thread and a connection to insert one record into the database is profligate. Instead, you could have one long-running thread with one connection which reads a queue. Every time it gets an item from the queue, it can insert it into the database. Then instead of spawning a thread for each insert, your main process simply puts data into the queue.

Comment: Ok that's a good way dealing with the situation. What if I have two or tree table to update should I pass the actual query or have different ques for every table?

Comment: I would pass a 2-tuple: `(sql, args)` with the `sql` being parametrized sql and the args itself a tuple of values. Using parametrized sql will help prevent sql injection.

Comment: Thank you that will do the job I will keep it in mind till monday. I will write some code and see the performance. Thank you for your time.